# Importing multi-module project into Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project that was made a while ago with a beta version of Android Studio. The project had two modules, one of which was an Android app, and the other an App Engine endpoints module. Both modules use gradle. The project was backed up using git.

Since I moved to another computer, I've been trying to import the project with the same structure from git into Android Studio. I can't get AS to recognise the module structure though. If I import directly from version control then AS doesn't see the gradle modules, and it's just one module with a bunch of sub packages. Then it won't let me import the modules as they already exist.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Android Studio is still not mature enough to be used a truly reliable and predictable tool. That is why I went back to Eclipse + ADT. Check this [bug #52962](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962) out for example.

Comment: You may also want to consult this neat [Android Studio vs. Eclipse: What You Need To Know](https://www.airpair.com/android/android-studio-vs-eclipse) article.

Comment: Why can't you just import each module one after the another ?